# Android: AlarmManager can be killed in TaskManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, taskmanager

When i use an AlarmManager it can be killed with the TaskManager, and never comes back. How does the Facebook app work? It doesn't show up in the Taskmanager but sends Notifications.. Even aver i've killed it.

Are they using Push Messages?

Or are they using a background-service... but how can it run all the time? A never ending while-loop with a sleep?

Comment: Android does not have something named "TaskManager". What specifically are you referring to?

Comment: when i press and hold the home button, then i get a box with a button "task manager" (android 2.3.3)

Comment: That is not part of Android, but rather something peculiar to your device.

Comment: i'm using a samsung galaxy s1... does that help? you mean android has nothing like a taskmanager to kill apps?

Comment: "you mean android has nothing like a taskmanager to kill apps?" -- Android has some options for killing apps. Only one ("Force Stop" button on the app's page in Settings) will cancel your alarms. However, Samsung is welcome to do whatever Samsung wants with Samsung's own "task manager".

Comment: ok.. i think the taskmanager does the same as the method you described

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found it by myselfe... in the onpause function i call

```
finish();
```

now my app doesn't show up in the taskmanager anymore, but the alarm manager is still called